# How to count the number of values in a column in a dataframe based on the values in the other dataframe

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have two dataframes. the first one is a raw dataframe so its item_value column has all the item values. and the other dataframe has columns named min,avg,max which has min,avg,max values specified for the items in the first dataframe. and I want to count the number of item values in the first dataframe based on the specified agg values in the second dataframe.
the first dataframe looks like this

| item_name | item_value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1.4 |
| A | 2.1 |
| B | 3.0 |
| A | 2.8 |
| B | 4.5 |
| B | 1.1 |

the second dataframe looks like this

| item_name | min | avg | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.1 | 2 | 2.7 |
| B | 2.1 | 3 | 4.0 |

I want to count the number of item values that are greater than the defined min,avg,max values in the other dataframe

So the result I want is

| item_name | min | avg | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Any help would be much appreciated
*please forgive my grammar

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind SQL implementation, you can try:

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView('df1')
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('df2')
sql = """
    select df2.item_name,
        sum(case when df1.item_value > df2.min then 1 else 0 end) as min,
        sum(case when df1.item_value > df2.avg then 1 else 0 end) as avg,
        sum(case when df1.item_value > df2.max then 1 else 0 end) as max
    from df2 join df1 on df2.item_name=df1.item_name
    group by df2.item_name
"""
df = spark.sql(sql)
df.show()
```